# S21 phase vs phase shift measure

Tags: rf, s-parameters

Hi am simulating in ADS microstrip T-lines for a 3 bit phase shifter, the lines are calculated to insert 55,110 and 220 phase shift for 2.16Ghz. With the S-Parameter simulation i can see the phase of the direct transmission coefficient which is consistent with the calculation, however looking at the voltage waves there is a difference between  the calculation and the phase of the coefficient. What could it be? Here is the simulation and results.[image: Schematic][image: results]

Comment: 385=360+25, and 25 isn’t that much different from 22.

Comment: Can you give more details about your “comparing 2 sin waves” method. How does it distinguish, for example, 0 degrees phase shift from 360 degrees?

Comment: I have a 3 bit phase shifter with a step of 55 degrees, so i have 8 states, one of them is 385 degrees. In the case 0 0 0 i have the reference output, 001 55 degrees and so on. Comparing the reference output wave with the last state wave i should have 385 degrees of phase shift but i have 364, but the phase of the S21 parameter for that state reads 385 in the same simulation.

Comment: Explain more about what you mean. What instrument are you using to compare the phases? What kind of probes are you using with it? How are you determining that the phase difference is 364 degrees and not 4 degrees or 724 degrees? We can't see over your shoulder and see what you're doing, you need to tell us.

Comment: Am doing the simulation in ADS using the S-parameter simulation and the Transient simulation block. To compare the signal i just look at the graph generated by the simulation, one being the phase of S21 using the unwrap(phase(S21)) command, and the second measurement watching the voltage waves of the output. What i am not sure is  that the phase of the S21 parameter(for one phase shift state) and the phase shift seen between the voltage waves (for the same phase shift state) have a difference being the worst case 22 degrees of difference between the S21 and waves measurement.

Comment: Please include an image showing your simulation setup for the time-domain case. Please edit your question to include the information needed to answer it. Comments are not permanent.

Comment: Done! Hope is more clear that way, thanks for the help.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. I am designing an active phase shifter and my voltage signals are showing the accurate phase shift and S21 does not have the same phae shift. (Just reverse of your case.)
Did you find any explanation?

Comment: @nainasinghal I converted your answer to a comment. I think you will now be able to comment directly.

Comment: @nainasinghal am not sure if its going to help in your case, but i found that without the losses of the microstrip and the insertion loss of the switches the phases are the same.